# LAStools blast2dem: error writing data for field "StripOffsets"

Tags: geotiff-tiff, lidar, lastools

I was processing an overage file to generate DTM and DSM using blast2dem. The generated DTM file can be viewed using ArcMap and ENVI. However, ArcMap and ENVI cannot open the generated DSM file. I don't know exactly what is the cause of this problem but there is an error reported every time I try to repeat the same process of generating DSM. It says:

> Error writing data for field "StripOffsets".

Please see the snapshot below. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

[image: blast2de3m error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above error means that the output TIFF generated by [BLAST](http://rapidlasso.com/BLAST) is too large (more than 2GB or more than a certain number of rows or columns) to be stored as a TIF file. Use the IMG format instead that can handle larger outputs. Unfortunately BigTIFF is not implemented at the moment.